# Coordinate axis transformation for robot manipulation

Tags: python, linear-algebra, ros, robotics, coordinate-transformation

This is a fairly generic robotics based Linear Algebra question, and I'm looking for an algorithm based mathematical approach to solve my problem and get an understanding, rather than a strictly ROS based answer.

I am trying out a custom picking of an object using a Robotic Arm. I have a separate perception module that detects objects and estimates the pose for grasping. It, however is in the camera frame and follows image processing convention of coordinate frames, i.e. with right:

> +x-axis, forward: +z-axis, down: +y-axis

From this perception module, I get two values - 3x3 Rotation matrix and 1x3 translation vector. 
As an example, say `T1`

```
Tra: [0.09014122 0.16243269 0.6211668 ]
Rot: [[ 0.          0.03210089 -0.99948463]
[ 0.          0.99948463  0.03210089]
[ 1.         -0.          0.        ]]
```

(i.e. I have to grasp at that location and in that orientation)
My robot base to camera transform is understandably in the right hand coordinate system. Here is an example of the same, say `T2`

```
translation: 
  x: 0.0564581200121
  y: 0.318823912978
  z: 0.452250135698
rotation: 
  x: -0.6954818376
  y: 0.693982204231
  z: -0.13156524004
  w: 0.13184954074
```

I am using `scipy.spatial.transform` to convert my poses from one format to another, so the actual implementation can handle any format of pose.

Now, to get the pose of the object from the robot, is a simple transformation T2 times T1. However, T1 follows a different convention from T2.

How would I go about this ? A detailed explanation using this example will be highly appreciated! I am trying to understand from scratch, hence I would prefer to arrive at a transformation matrix on my own to apply to the above ones to get the final pose.

This question probably belongs to Mathematics Stack Exchange and ROS as well, but as I mentioned, I am trying to approach it analytically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the pose of the object by multiplying T2*T1, both T1, T2 must be in the homogeneous coordinates, where T1, T2 contain rotation matrix and translation. And the size of T1, T2 should be 4x4 for 3D.

[image]

In your case, the orientation of T2 is represented in Quaternion. Convert this into rotation matrix and create a homogeneous matrix using rotation matrix, translation.

Comment: Hello. Apologies for the late reply. This does not seem to be working. Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: can you show your homogeneous matrix for t1 and t2 transformation?

Comment: Hey @nayab . Apologies, I read it correctly now. I was multiplying T1*T2. and not T2*T1. Now it makes sense. Sorry!